# Red x appearing above "rendered output" tab in Suggested edits queue

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

While reviewing Suggested edits, I noticed that a message was appearing on top of the "Rendered output" button:

[image]

This is the fourth time I'm seeing this. This doesn't happen every time, and is quite rare. But it happens :(

This looks like a bug to me.

If it matters: I use Google Chrome version 41.0.2272.101 (64-bit). I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

---

I just got some more information to our progress.

I reproduced this on this edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12310148

I inspected the source, but I actually could not find anything like a message. The closest thing I got:

```
&lt;div id="noscript-warning"&gt;Stack Overflow works best with JavaScript enabled&lt;img src="http://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc.gif" alt="" class="dno"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

I finally got what the popup is consisting of. It looks very silly. Here is the code I got after inspecting the element:

```
<div class="popup-close"><a title="close this popup (or hit Esc)">×</a></div>
```

The 'x' is also being printed on the popup, which shows that this is mostly the code.

I got this on: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12323228

Comment: It's obviously part of one of those dialogs. The next time you see it happen, try inspecting the source to see if there's a message that's being cut off. This could give some important information about when and why it's happening.

Comment: @Laurel Okay. I'll do that.

Comment: IIRC, this has been reported before. But I can't find the dup! :-/

Comment: @CoolGuy If you find the dupe, please inform me. I'll be happy to close it as dupe if it certainly is. I couldn't find a dupe so I posted this, but looks like my search was not enough :(

Comment: The red cross is there? that post must need major editing help

Comment: a link to the review where you're seeing this would also be helpful...

Comment: @m0sa Sorry, I can't find the review on which this appeared. If I get it again, I'll inform you, and also give the review.

Comment: I had a similar strange error today too. Said (something along the lines of) "your not logged in", even though I was. I refreshed and it went away.

Comment: @m0sa I got a repro on this review: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12292964

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ your review did get recorded, did you re-submit it?

Comment: @m0sa Yes, I refreshed the page finding that the x was gone. Then I submitted my review. I've edited my q

Comment: @Laurel Edited q.

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ It wouldn't make sense for that to be the error message. After all, I think that you need JS enabled to see the popup in the first place.

Comment: @Laurel I agree, but that was the closest I got. And I don't know whether it need js enabled or not; I don't even know if js in enabled :P

Answer (score 1):

We need to get some more information about this bug. I suspect that it only happens on certain set ups, because I have never seen this happen to me. But I may know how to reliably reproduce it.

We don't know yet if *all* error popups result in this behavior, but I think that it will be helpful to know *one* error that causes this behavior. Or if we can rule out any errors as the culprit. (Have you ever had a normal looking error?)

I can easily trigger this non-defective error message by loading a review, turning off my wi-fi (so that I have no internet connection), and clicking approve:

[image: review error]

In the wild, this error is caused by poor unreliable connections. Of course, this would result in the error appearing inconsistently, and this may be why you rarely are encountering the bug.

If you can trigger the bug in this manner, it opens up the avenue to experimentation (for example, by resizing the window) and should help the developers to fix the bug.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I nearly got the code for the dialog. See my edit.